# Visual Studio Office 365 SharePoint Apps - codebhind and C# classes SharePoint Hosted

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013, office365-apps

Did a simple deployment of sharePoint Hosted App from Visual Studio... it worked - but I want to understand the limits of what I can do from visual studio.

I see no aspx page cs codebehind in the solution. Any way to do that?
I added a c# class, but will I be able to reference it?
so, If I want to bind SPO List data to a asp.net gridview, where/how should I do that?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharepoint hosted application means you need to access sharepoint using the client model, so be ready to use jQuery a lot. In this type of application you need to create all your logics on client as the app gets installed within sharepoint 365 and its very picky with what you install there, after all, it a microsoft server, so it's sandboxed to the fullest.

However, if you want to have a more traditional approach, try with autohosted, there you have codebehind, aspx, classes... The whole nine yards. Bear in mind, with autohosted you will have to deal a lot with cross scripting and you will need your own hosting (provider hosted) or an azure account to deploy as all the code is deployed to your hosting and just reference to the application is installed on 365.

Check

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179930.aspx
- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58479/is-there-a-difference-between-a-sharepoint-hosted-app-and-a-cloud-hosted-app

Comment: Excellent information, but this opens a can of worms I think about deployment and authentication.  For example, our SPO is authenticated with ADFS on local servers. And, I'll need to test this, but do I need to split my application to account for parts that will  run in Azure vs. SPO? And if I go CSOM only, possible bind an SPO list to an asp.net datagrid control with jquery CSOM with no serverside c# code?

Comment: Another question.. will I need SharePoint 2013 Foundation installed on my dev machine I go autohosted? I just created the solution this way and waiting to see when it will ask for my Azure information. So far, only asked for SPO login.

Comment: So.. I deployed an autohosted via VS 2012 and it never asked me for Azure information. I see the app in all content. When will it ask for Azure information? and how do I make the app available to other site collection? Right now, the url for the app looks like this ..https://1e9a4afa-c77b-460e-b17a-8eded45c2200.o365apps.net/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmiamiedu%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2Fsites%2Fdev&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=2&SPProductNumber=16%2E0%2E1922%2E1221

Comment: Most probably you have deployed in debug, in this case, the host is your cassini process within vs :). All I see is the sadly known yellow page

Comment: yes, definitely cassini. Need to figure out how to actually deploy. •Make sure the web address https://localhost:44305 is correct.

Comment: I created and published an autohosted spo app... or so I think I did.  It needed an azure subscription which I have.  when I debug, it goes to spo, but the url points back to local (cassini I think).  If I publish it takes me to a blank azure website because I set to publish there.. since not sure where else to publish  Totally confused about deployment and how authentication will work. Not how I will share and secure the application either. :)

Comment: To add to the confusion, the SPO app catalog wants a file you downloaded.  I deployed to Azure websites - was that a wrong? :) Thanks and sorry.

Comment: I'm not on my laptop to test run what you said, sorry. In the meantime, why don't you open another question? If I can't answer you, someone might!

Comment: Posted. I was able to add new app to the SPO app catalog  by uploading the .app file and was able to install an run it on another site collection and the app had c# code behind and I never specified my azure subscription. But, I still must use the CSOM to get to SharePoint List Data. I'm wonder if I can bind to asp.net gridview using CSOM from c# and deploying to SPO and not using my Azure subscription?